# I want the first checkbox to be autochecked when any of the other checkox are checked

Tags: php, html, jquery, laravel

```
<div class="form-group row">
                <div class="col-xs-10">
                    <h5 style="margin-bottom: 12px;">@lang('admin.roles.pages')</h5>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <div class="col-xs-2">
                        <?php
                        $page_view = check_permission('pagelist', $id);
                        ?>
                        <input <?php if ($page_view == 1) {
                                    echo 'checked=checked';
                                }  ?> style="float: left;" type="checkbox"  value="admin.List-Page" name="roles[pagelist]" id="pageview">
                        <label style="float: left; margin-left: 5px; margin-top: 6px;" for="pageview">View</label>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-xs-2">
                        <?php
                        $page_create = check_permission('pagecreate', $id);
                        ?>
                        <input <?php if ($page_create == 1) {
                                    echo 'checked=checked';
                                }  ?> style="float: left;" type="checkbox" value="admin.Create-Page" name="roles[pagecreate]" id="pagecreate">
                        <label style="float: left; margin-left: 5px; margin-top: 6px;" for="pagecreate">Create</label>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-xs-2">
                        <?php
                        $page_edit = check_permission('pageedit', $id);
                        ?>
                        <input <?php if ($page_edit == 1) {
                                    echo 'checked=checked';
                                }  ?> style="float: left;" type="checkbox" value="admin.Edit-Page" name="roles[pageedit]" id="pageedit">
                        <label style="float: left; margin-left: 5px; margin-top: 6px;" for="pageedit">Edit</label>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-xs-2">
                        <?php
                        $page_delete = check_permission('pagedelete', $id);
                        ?>
                        <input <?php if ($page_delete == 1) {
                                    echo 'checked=checked';
                                }  ?> style="float: left;" type="checkbox" value="admin.Delete-Page" name="roles[pagedelete]" id="pagedelete">
                        <label style="float: left; margin-left: 5px; margin-top: 6px;" for="pagedelete">Delete</label>
                    </div>
```

Here I want checkbox view to be autoselected when checkbox create or delete or update are checked.
that is keeping the view checkbox selected automatically while selecting any of the other

Comment: in php or jquery?

Comment: I just posted a jQuery solution.  Is that what you were looking for?  I can't think of a reason why you would want to do this with PHP instead.

Comment: ya i need in jquery

Answer (score 0):

Check for .length > 0 for the three checkboxes that don't have the id of the checkbox that you want to check automatically.  Use the .prop jQuery function to check and uncheck the #pageview checkbox.

```js
function autoChecked() {
    if ($("input[type=checkbox]:not(#pageview):checked").length > 0) {
        $("#pageview").prop("checked", true);
    } else if ($("input[type=checkbox]:not(#pageview):checked").length  == 0) 
    {
       $("#pageview").prop("checked", false)
    }
};
$($("input[type=checkbox]:not(#pageview)")).on("change", function(event) {
    autoChecked();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" name="pagecreate" value="0" /> Checkbox 1  
  <input type="checkbox" name="pageedit" value="0" /> Checkbox 2
  <input type="checkbox" name="pagedelete" value="0" /> Checkbox 3 
</div>
<BR><BR>
<input type="checkbox" id="pageview" name="pageview" value="0" /> This checkbox will become checked if one or more of the other checkboxes are checked.
```

Comment: Note that this is invalid html. The `name` attribute should either be unique or turned into an array (if you want to pass multiple values). If names are the same, when the form is submitted, only the last value will be passed, because it overwrites the previous ones.

Comment: Thanks, I just fixed it so that the name attribute is unique for all the checkboxes.

Answer (score 0):

you could just write this:

```
$("input #pageview").checked = $("input[type=checkbox]:not(#pageview):checked").length > 0;
```

`$("input[type=checkbox]:not(#pageview):checked").length`

means:

give me the number of tag input checkbox which have not the id `pageview` and which are checked